# How can I assign different heights to cells EXCEL 2016?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to make a table in Excel 2016, but I had a problem which is assigning specific heights to specific cells. (Please, refer to the image below)

[image]

Comment: It's impossible without doing cell merging.

Comment: And how can I do it after I merge cells. I mean, I literally tried everything I could but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge `A1:A2`, `B1:B2`, `C1:C2`, etc.

Apply this formatting to the left-side columns by selecting the merged cells and dragging down on the little green square on the bottom right corner of the selection box.

[image]

Merge `D2:D3`, `E2:E3`, `F2:F3`, etc.

Repeat for the right-side columns

(It might be helpful to memorise the key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd> to merge selected cells.)

You'll get the results you want, but beware the sheet is a bit weird now. Each row is two rows away from its neighbour, for example. Selecting and formatting are likely to not work the way you'd expect. Good luck!

[image: staggered rows as desired]

Comment: Can you tell me how did you make the "heights" of the (C, D and E)'s cells different... That's what I'm still struggling with. Tnx in adv!